# Why does the if statement ignore the first if?

Tags: python

```
myList = [5, 8, 5]

x = int(input("Enter a number: "))

if x in myList:
    if myList.index(x) == 0 and myList.index(x) == 2:
        print(x, "is in 1st and 3rd place!") 
    elif myList.index(x) == 0:
        print(x, "is in 1st place!") 
    elif myList.index(x) == 2:
        print(x, "is in 3rd place!")
```

Entering 5 in the input
expecting output:

`>>> 5 is in 1st and 3rd place!`

actual output:

`>>> 5 is in 1st place!`

Comment: `index` only finds the first occurrence of an element.

Comment: Because 0 does not equal 2. `myList.index(x)` cannot simultaneously be *both* zero *and* two.

Comment: use a for loop with enumerate rather than if statements

Comment: i don't understand the logic that is desired

Comment: `myList.index(x) == 0 and myList.index(x) == 2` - what value of `myList.index(x)` are you imagining which could equal 0 and also equal 2? Python isn't ignoring it, it's testing your condition and your condition is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index` returns the first occurrence of the element in the list. Instead of checking the `index` of the user input, you could directly check the value of the element in the required position:

```py
if myList[0] == x and myList[2] == x:
    print(x, "is in 1st and 3rd place!") 
elif myList[0] == x:
    print(x, "is in 1st place!") 
elif myList[2] == x:
    print(x, "is in 3rd place!")
```

Comment: Thank you, i am a beginner and  forgot about this.

Answer (score 0):

Index method return lowest index of the elementi that you search for. In your case , for your test, It return the index zero (lowest index between zero and Two)

Answer (score 0):

First of the first `if statement` is not ignored, it is evaluated to be `False`.
Why that happens? Because `.index()` finds only the first element in a list so you basically compare this: `if 0 == 0 and 0 == 2:`, obviously it will be `False`

A better approach to find all occurrences of an element in a list would be this:

```py
my_lst = [5, 8, 5]
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
occurrences = [str(index + 1) for index, value in enumerate(my_lst) if value == x]
print(f'{x} is in place(s) {", ".join(occurrences)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when you only give one parameter in index it will consider first appearance in the list. Try to give the index position after the first appearance.
Try this like:

```py
if myList.index(x) == 0 and myList.index(x, 1) == 2:
```